# insert doc file into the current oppened document at cursor point (using insertFileFromBase64 )

Tags: ms-word, office-js

Here I am trying to insert a doc file at cursor point from my Office Add-in to Word , but I could not find the proper solution.
The API has only three options :

```js
bodyObject.insertFileFromBase64(base64File, insertLocation);
```

where `insertLocation` can be `Start`, `End` or `Replace`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The options for [`Word.InsertLocation`](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/word/enums#wordinsertlocation) are:

- `Start`: Prepend the inserted content *before* the existing content.
- `End`: Append the inserted content *after* the existing contents.
- `Replace`: Replace the existing content with the inserted content.

When you using [`bodyObject.insertFileFromBase64`](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/word/body#insertfilefrombase64base64file-string-insertlocation-string), you're scoping your call to the entire Body of the document. Calling this method will therefore not care about your cursor location.

I suspect that you really want here is [`rangeObject.insertFileFromBase64`](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/word/enums#wordinsertlocation). This is scoped to a Range rather than the entire Body. You can fetch a range from the current selection (or if nothing is selected, your cursor location):

```js
Word.run(function (context) {

    // Queue a command to get the current selection and then
    // create a proxy range object with the results.
    var range = context.document.getSelection();

    // Queue a commmand to insert base64 encoded .docx at the beginning of the range.
    // You'll need to implement getBase64() to make this work.
    range.insertFileFromBase64(getBase64(), Word.InsertLocation.start);

    // Synchronize the document state by executing the queued commands,
    // and return a promise to indicate task completion.
    return context.sync().then(function () {
        console.log('Added base64 encoded text to the beginning of the range.');
    });
})
.catch(function (error) {
    console.log('Error: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
    if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
        console.log('Debug info: ' + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
    }
});
```

Comment: WOW , its working absolutely fine. Thanks a ton You saved me.